# Given $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\in C^2$ s.t. $∆f > 0$ prove that $\frac{d\int_{\partial B(0,r)}f}{dr} > 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, greens-theorem

Given $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\in C^2$ s.t. $∆f > 0$ prove that $\frac{d\int_{\partial B(0,r)}f}{dr} > 0$.

I know that this is just using Green's first formula, but I'm having a little bit of trouble applying it. I know that $\int_{\partial B(0,r)}Df_N > 0$, but I can't seem to formally prove that that is enough for this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $f(0,0,0)=0?$

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: What if $f(x,y,z) = -1 +x^2+y^2+z^2.$ Isn't the integral $-4\pi r^2 + 4\pi r^4,$ whose derivative is negative for small $r$?